# How to pass form input field value to external page using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where I would like to pass the value of an text input field to an external page without a form submit event. I would like to field value to become a php variable on the external page.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            cityField = $('#the_form input[id=city]');
                 $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "external.php",
    data:{ city: cityfield }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }
        });
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Within the external.php page, I would like to declare the city form field value as a php variable as

```
$city = $_POST['city'];
```

Comment: Do you want to run this function on page load?

Answer (score 0):

To start with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

and

```
$(function() {
```

are equivalent. The $(function() should be something like

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
```

so that when you click the button, it runs the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I dont feel right posting an answer for a single change... But
EDIT: There are actually a few things...

```
<!-- For .click() -->
<a href="#" id="doStuff">Click Me!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // $(function() { // Trigger on page load
    // $('#doStuff').click(function() { // Trigger on a click
    $('#city').blur(function() { // Trigger when the focus on the field is lost (click away, tab to another field, ect)
    // $('#city').change(function() { // Trigger when the fields value changes
        var cityField = $('#city');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "external.php",
            data:{ 'city': cityField.val() }, 
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Changes:

- You dont need `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})` AND `$(function(){ })`. Its the same thing.
- Its smart to put a `var` in front on your variables.
- Case is important. `cityField` and `cityfield` are not the same thing
- You were just sending the whole dom element to your external script. (which I assume you only wanted the contents of the input)
- Also, you dont need to look for "an input, with an 'id' attribute , with a value of 'city'". Just look for `#city`

**EDIT:**
Your updated code (just putting it here so its easier to see):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#city').blur(function() {
        var cityField=$('#city').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"autosuggest.php",
            data:{'cityField':cityField },
            dataType:"text",
            complete:function(data, status) {
                alert("You typed: "+cityField);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your data will should be available in `autosuggest.php` as `$_POST['cityField'];`

Having a `status` check within the success function, is a little redundant, in my opinion.
It would be better to move the `success:function(data,...` to a `complete:function(data,...`

Comment: Thank you for helping me clean up the code. How would I pass city value to external.php without a click function?

Comment: See the edit ^. Basically, create an element with a specific ID, then change the `$(function(){ })` to listen for click events: `$('#yourId').click(function(){ })`. That link, can be anything. It was just simplest to go with that

Comment: When exactly do you want to send the value?  What would trigger this if not a button click?

Comment: Wait... @MatRichardson is right. What possible action would you want other than a click? I just woke up. It sounded like you were ASKING for it to become a click.

Comment: Is it possible to send the value of the city input field to external.php when the visitor leaves the field continuing to the next form field?

Comment: Absolutely. `.blur()` But remember, it will fire (and send the request) anytime the user clicks away, regardless if the fields value changes or not. You probably want `.change()`. Also, I added a few other methods (just so you are aware of some other things out there)

Comment: @Oberst thanks for your help. I cleaned up the code, its capturing the field value but not passing it to external.php. <script type="text/javascript">
    
   $('#city').blur(function() {
  
             var cityField = document.querySelector('#city').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "autosuggest.php",
            data: {'cityField': cityField }, 
   dataType: "text",
            success: function(data, status){
     if(status=="success") {
             alert("You typed: " + cityField);
     }
            }
            });
        });
   </script>

Comment: Ahh. I was tired when I was doing this. `city` needs quotes. See the edit. It should be accessible to your `external.php` file as `$_POST['city'];` now.

Comment: Why did you change `$('#city').val()` to `document.querySelector('#city').value`? If you are using jQuery, why not continue to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the code but the data is not being sent to external.php. It is being set but not posting. Here is my revised code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

       $('#city').blur(function() {

        var cityField = document.querySelector('#city').value;
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "external.php",
        data: {'cityField': cityField }, 
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data, status){
             if(status=="success") {
         alert("You typed: " + cityField);
             }
        }
        });
    });
```